# Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home/a3598479/public_html/Register.php on line 8

Tags: php, mysqli, authentication

Please help me. I don't actually use PHP but I need to use in my Login/Register project.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("***", "***", "***", "***");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO user (name, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;  

echo json_encode($response);
```

But it says

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() [function.mysqli-stmt-bind-param]: Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables in /home/a3598479/public_html/Register.php on line 8
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: `siss` should probably be only `sss`.

Comment: just as the error states. vtc as a typo. question like this has been asked too many times.

Comment: @FirstOne *probably*.... => *Must* ;-)

Comment: Thanks FirstOne. Like I said I do not use php at all.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I probably (now it is _probably_ hehe) give too much credit to people asking. Maybe they forgot to add something to the query ;)

Comment: Flagged as a `simple typographical error` ;)

Comment: @FirstOne if that extra `i` was removed by them and still fails, then something else is failing them, being an unknown variable/POST array. if it solved it, great! 2 points for you ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I think problem in following statement:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $username, $password);
```

You are passing `siss` which means it there should be 4 `params` with types `string`, `integer`, `string` and `string` which is wrong as you have only `three parameters` which are all string.

So the statement should be like this:

```
 mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $name, $username, $password);
```

Comment: You can test it before inserting by another statment:
`$getUser = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE name=?') ;
$getUser->bind_param('s', $name);
$getUser->execute();
$getUser->store_result();
$countRows = $getUser->num_rows;
if($countRows >0)
{
   $response["error"] = 'User already exists';  
}`